# Can the mdy function in SAS accept character as well as numeric values?

Tags: date, sas

I am wondering what data the mdy function in SAS will accept.

Specifically, can I submit the mdy function as such:

`mdy("01", 01, 1960)`, and get `0`?

The documentation is unhelpful:  it states, "(the function) returns a SAS date value from month, day, and year values."

If SAS does not complain about the data types, is this because it is doing an implicit char to num conversion?  Or is it just accepting the char data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**documentation**](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lefunctionsref/67239/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0bo5thbfrcab1n1menkqxq2suiv.htm) is quite clear that the MDY function expects numeric values for the arguments, either as variables or constants.

And yes, if you supply character values, they will be converted to numeric before execution.  Unless you have turned off warning messages, your SAS log will have a note to that effect.

Comment: So the function takes a numeric variable, but in practice it doesn't matter, because SAS will implicitly convert the data type.